# YAMLException: Class not found trying to call constructor of class not in models package

Tags: java, playframework, yaml, playframework-1.x, snakeyaml

I'm trying to construct some classes using Play1 (v1.3.1) fixtures as follows:

```
Advertisement(advert1):
    serviceClass: FREE_WITH_ADS
    type: IMAGE
    advertiserName: Test Advertiser
    advertiserImage: !!utils.binaryfield.ImageBlob [ /local/adverts/test.jpg, image/jpeg ]
    advertiserUrl: http://www.google.com
    strapline: Test strapline
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Class not found: utils.binaryfield.ImageBlob
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor.getClassForNode(Constructor.java:650)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.getConstructor(Constructor.java:331)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:341)
    ... 26 more
```

The issue is with the advertiserImage field and calling the constructor for ImageBlob of which the SnakeYAML parser cannot find the class. Am I calling the constructor correctly and if so then what do I need to do to enable the SnakeYAML parser to have visibility of classes outside of the models package? I would be surprised if Play1 hasn't initialised the SnakeYAML classpath with all the available app packages.

The ImageBlob constructor signature is:

```
public ImageBlob(String uri, String mimeType)
```

and I'm calling the fixture as follows:

```
@OnApplicationStart
public class Bootstrap extends Job {
    public void doJob() {
        // Populate local in-memory database for manual testing.
        if (User.count() == 0 && Play.configuration.get("db").equals("mem") && !Play.runingInTestMode()) {
            String mode = (String) Play.configuration.get("application.mode");
            Fixtures.loadModels(((mode != null) ? "initial-data-dev.yml" : "initial-data.yml"));
        }
    }
}
```

==== UPDATE 29/8/15 ====

I've now also tried the following alternative:

```
utils.binaryfield.ImageBlob(testBlob):
    url: /local/adverts/test.jpg
    mimeType: image/jpeg

Advertisement(advert1):
    serviceClass: FREE_WITH_ADS
    type: IMAGE
    advertiserName: Test Advertiser
    advertiserImage: testBlob
    advertiserUrl: http://www.google.com
    strapline: Test strapline
```

and getting this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: models.utils.binaryfield.ImageBlob
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:91)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at play.test.Fixtures.loadModels(Fixtures.java:236)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 1):

May be I am bit late to respond, but it will help others in future.

This issue comes when your class is not able to load the class, sometimes even if it is present in your classpath also.

I encountered this Issue and can be handled in this way.

```
package my.test.project;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.CustomClassLoaderConstructor;
public class MyTestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream input = MyTestClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.yml");
        Yaml y = new Yaml(new CustomClassLoaderConstructor(MyTestClass.class.getClassLoader()));
        TestConfig test =y.loadAs(input, TestConfig.class);
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

You need to initialize Yaml object with ***CustomClassLoaderConstructor*** it will help load the bean class before it was actually used internally.

Comment: solve my problem: spark app run on yarn(cluster mode)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
utils.binaryfield.ImageBlob(myBlob):
    uri: /some/path
    mimeType: some/mime

Advertisement(advert1):
    # (...)
    advertiserImage: byBlob
    # (...)
```

If you still get the same error please add the code you use to load the yaml (fixtures?) to your question

Comment: Now I'm getting the following exception - it's now explicitly looking in the models package...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: models.utils.binaryfield.ImageBlob
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:91)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at play.test.Fixtures.loadModels(Fixtures.java:236)
 ... 10 more